# Dynamics 365 client secret authentication

Tags: dynamics-crm

We were using the Office365 authentication inorder to connect to the CRM from c# code. when we started changing it to client secret authentication type the connection to the CRM became very slow.

We have batch job which connects to CRM and gets the data from CRM. Previously on Office365 authentication it takes 2 mins for retrieving 1300 records, however with client secret authentication it take 50 minutes.

```cs
CrmServiceClient.MaxConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
var ConnectionStringClientSecret1 = string.Format("AuthType={0}; Url={1}; AppId={2}; ClientSecret = {3};", authType, organizationUri, appId, clientSecret);
CrmServiceClient connection = new CrmServiceClient(ConnectionStringClientSecret1);
proxy = connection;
```

Anyone had faced this issue or is there any workaround for fixing the issue.

Comment: Could you share some code? How do you authenticate? During a run does your code log on multiple times? Does your code cache the security token?

Comment: I am using the following code  
I just changed the authentication type from Office 365 to ClientCredentials and given the client id and client secret. I am not generating any security token. Here is the code i am using. If i need to use the cache of security token, please let me know

Comment: ```CrmServiceClient.MaxConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
    var ConnectionStringClientSecret1 = string.Format("AuthType={0}; Url={1}; AppId={2}; ClientSecret = {3};", authType, organizationUri, appId, clientSecret);
     CrmServiceClient connection = new CrmServiceClient(ConnectionStringClientSecret1);
                    proxy = connection;```

Comment: Just to be sure: what AuthType are you passing? On D365 OnLine sometimes you can experience a fallback in performance, especially in sandbox environments. This can be caused by massive workloads on other organizations that are on the same server. It can also be caused by automatic solution imports and various upgrades. Maybe you can just try again?

Comment: I am using the clientcredentials authentication. Also we are using D365 online and that to on Government subscription. Also the performance issue is not sometimes, once we had migrated to ClientCredentials, we started facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string should start with "AuthType=ClientSecret;" and it should contain a token cache path setting, e.g. "TokenCacheStorePath=C:\Temp\myaadappregtoken.bin;"

Comment: It didnt worked same behavior.

Comment: I used the following ```var ConnectionStringClientSecret1 = string.Format("AuthType={0}; Url={1}; AppId={2}; ClientSecret = {3};TokenCacheStorePath = D:\\Temp\\myaadappregtoken.bin;", authType, organizationUri, appId, clientSecret);```

Answer (score 0):

Enabled verbose logging, and check the log.
I would suspect your being throttled.

to enabled, see: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/xrm-tooling/configure-tracing-xrm-tooling)